# Creating dynamic Linq query based on property values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that contains a number of properties of type bool.

```
public class FilterModel 
{
    public bool Hotel { get; set; }
    public bool Apartment { get; set; }
    public bool Guesthouse { get; set; }

}
```

I am constructing a LINQ query dynamically based on whether or not these properties are true or false.
For example if I had an instance of this class and Hotel was set to true.
I want to generate a LINQ query something like

```
var q = from accom in db.Accommodation
                     where accom.Hotel == true 
                     select accom;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
IQueryable<Accommodation> query = db.Accommodation;

if (filterModel.Hotel)      query = query.Where(a => a.Hotel);
if (filterModel.Apartment)  query = query.Where(a => a.Apartment);
if (filterModel.Guesthouse) query = query.Where(a => a.Guesthouse);

return query;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
var filterModel = GetFilterModelFromSomewhere();
var q = db.Accomodation;

if (filterModel.Hotel)
    q = q.Where(accom => accom.Hotel);

if (filterModel.Apartment)
    q = q.Where(accom => accom.Apartment);

if (filterModel.Guesthouse)
    q = q.Where(accom => accom.Guesthouse);
```

Since the query isn't executed until you enumerate it (via ToList() or an equivalent function) you can build it piecemeal in code based on dynamic conditions.